# Unable to download .AAR file for HERE-Premium Android SDK

Tags: here-api

I've created a freemium account and was going through the documentation for HERE-Android premium SDK to the point where I needed to download the AAR file to place in the .lib file.

I can't access the website to download it, is anyone having this problem as well?? or is it just me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should find the link to the sdk when you create your credentials.

Sign in to developer.here.com , click on your active project, scroll down to "HERE SDK for Android (Premium Edition)" and click on "Generate AppId ...".

After the generation is done you'll find the link at the very bottom of the page.